# checking duplicates in list using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to check for duplicate numbers within a list using only while loops and if statements. For some reason it is returning True for the list [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and I can't figure out why.

```
def has_duplicates(xs):
count = 0
while count < len(xs) and len(xs) > 1:
    check = 1
    while check < len(xs):
        if xs[check] == xs[count]:
            return True
        else:
            check += 1
    count += 1
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the correct output using your function. However, there are certainly easier ways to get the same result, as:

```
def has_duplic2(xs):
    return len(set(xs)) != len(xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first algorithm you shouldn't assing to the `check` variable the value of 1.
Otherwise on the second cycle of the loop both `count` and `check` will be 1 and you'll be comparing the element [1] of your list with itself, which will always return true.

Instead you should set the `check` variable to `check = count + 1`. So that you never compare a value with itself.